# How to put google map field in my form of my custom module?

Tags: forms, 8, google-maps

i like to build a form field based on google map, where user can put in their address, city and country, then the map will automatically search for it.
and then you can put a pin to define the exact location, which the expected output is latitude & longitude which will be saved during form submit.

how to approach this? is there any module in Drupal 8 that i can use during form generation?

maybe something like:

```
 $form['map'] = array(
      '#type' => 'gmap',
      '#otherProperty' => propertyValues,
 );
```

Thank you,
AnD

Answer (score -1):

use this 
it works for me
https://www.drupal.org/project/google_map_field
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.